# Problems tracking Ecommerce with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to add tracking tags to my Web site. Event and tracking rules are working fine, but not the transactional ones.

```
        _gaq.push(['_addTrans', commande, '', tot_commande]);
         foreach(...){
        _gaq.push(['_addItem', commande, code_form[i], nom_form[i], "", prix[i], nbr_part[i]]);
           }
        _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

Example with var

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans', 59, '',1772]);
_gaq.push(['_addItem', 59,K52171088-2013-20130612,Déchets industriels...,1772,1]);
```

I have no error in my console, but in my Google Analytics dashboard I found nothing concerning the transactions.

Thanks for your help

Comment: all looks ok, all parrameters that are required are there. are values properly formated? maybe is price with "," and not "." ?

Comment: no the price is without comma !

Comment: `transactionId` (commande) is unique?

Comment: _gaq.push(['_addTrans', 59, '',1772]);

Comment: _gaq.push(['_addItem', 59,K52171088-2013-20130612,Déchets industriels...,1772,1]);

Comment: try adding all text in quotes (') also check if your texts does not have quotes inside. Javascript does not like french language. :)

Comment: javascript doesn't like ANY text outside of quotes.  ALL text should be surrounded by quotes. Otherwise javascript will attempt to parse it as a number or variable. However..I think he was just showing an example of what the values are..looks like in the first code snippet, he is using variables.

Comment: do you see the request being made to google? If so, how long have you waited before looking at the reports? Data can take up to 24 hours to show up.

Comment: no, the last request i have on the network console is for the page loaded :           _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Section', 'Panier', 3]);

Comment: I am trying since yesterday morning !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> always call _trackTrans after _trackPageview!

this was my prbleme ! explained here:  [Google analytics doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce)

Thanks